# Need to 'convert' an MySQL-query to Eloquent; where to start / how to think?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'd like to 'convert' a raw SQL-query to Eloquent, so I can have eager loaded models attached too, so I don't have to edit some templates I got. Problem is, the query got some subqueries and I do not know how to 'convert' the query into Eloquent's format. The query in question is:

```
SELECT
     e_eh.id,
     s.name as serie,
     s.id as serie_id,
     e_eh.season,
     e_eh.episode,
     e_eh.name,
     eh1.prog_trans,
     eh1.prog_check,
     eh1.prog_sync,
     eh1.avi
FROM (
    SELECT
        e.*
        , (
            SELECT
                eh.id
            FROM episode_histories AS eh
            WHERE 1
            AND eh.episode_id = e.id
            ORDER BY
                eh.id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS eh_id
    FROM episodes AS e
    WHERE 1
    AND e.completed = 0
    AND e.deleted_at IS NULL
) AS e_eh
INNER JOIN episode_histories AS eh1 ON e_eh.eh_id = eh1.id
INNER JOIN series as s ON s.id = e_eh.serie_id
ORDER BY prog_trans DESC, prog_check DESC, prog_sync DESC
```

I've tried a few things already, but none have worked. I'm a bit stuck in how to "think" this into Laravel / Eloquent. Documentation from Laravel itself is also not much helpful.

In a nutshell:
I've got two models, one is episodes, other is episode_histories, whichs stores some history on related episode. A third model is the show model, the related show for it. I need to get an episode, with related show model (is a relation in my model already). but I also need to get the latest episode_histories model for given episode.

What I currently have in my models:

Episode:
`class Episode extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use App\History; // The history model

```
protected $table        = 'episodes';
protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
public    $timestamps   = true;

/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

/* Eloquent relations */
public function show() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Serie', 'serie_id', 'id');
}

public function history() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\History', 'episode_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}

public static function getEpisodes2() {
    return DB::select();
}
```

}
`And my history model looks like this:`
class History extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

```
protected $table        = 'episode_histories';
protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
public    $timestamps   = true;

/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

/* Eloquent relations */
public function episode() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Episode');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}

/* Custom functions */
```

}`
I hope someone can help me out on this. In the event of missing info, please let me know, so I can add that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this query types I would recommend you to use the [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries). Take a look at the documentation

Comment: If the query builder can also return related models (eager loading), then I'm sure I can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice when for dealing with complex queries is to keep it raw. Other than that, you have models for the helping hand because when a change comes to this query, there is a lot of editing and reshuffling again to blend it to a perfect state.

```
DB:statement("your query")
```

If you have procedures, then:

```
DB::statement('CALL PROCEDURE_NAME(:id,@name,@email);',array($id);
$result = DB:select('select @name as alias_name, @email as alias_name');
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I can better 'run' this query raw? Hmmm, was hoping Eloquent could help me out, so I don't have to edit some templates, which relies on some relations through Eloquent.